# how to download a csv generated from papaparse?

Tags: javascript, csv, vue.js, papaparse

I have successfully managed to unparse a json to csv using papaparse. I have stored the generated csv in a variable. On a button click, the csv is being generated and I can see the result in my console. I want to download that csv generated into my local system when I click the button. How do I do that?

`const csv = Papa.unparse(csvData);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code

```
var csv = Papa.unparse(array);

var csvData = new Blob([csv], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});

var csvURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvData);

var testLink = document.createElement('a');
testLink.href = csvURL;
testLink.setAttribute('test', 'test.csv');
testLink.click();
```

Comment: Are you we set csvURL to null. I am getting an error because of that.

Comment: try this var csvURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
Comment  this line - var csvURL =  null;

Comment: I tried this but nothing seems to happen on a click. Even in code pen when I click on the button nothing is being downloaded. Do you know what could be the problem? Is it working in your system through the button at code pen?

Comment: Perfect! it works now. Thats a lot for your help. Can you briefly explain what you did there?

Comment: i have just created blob object with your data. after this i have created a url using createurl whitch return the url represting object given in the parameter and then created tempopary hyperlink to download the file. for more detail visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL